# Which [Windows] privileges are considered administrative privileges?

Tags: windows, security

I heard about administrative privileges a lot but I could not find out which privileges *are* administrative privileges.

For example, the [DeleteProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function requires administrative privileges. Does it mean that it requires the user to be an administrator, or the local system account, i.e. having *all* the administrative privileges, in order to execute it? I'd like to know the exact set of privileges required by such function.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: It wouldn't mean the local system account, since you aren't going to (shouldn't) write code that executes as the system. If you're calling an API, it's referring to the Administrators group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when a function is documented as "the caller must have administrative privileges" then the function explicitly checks that the caller is a member of the Administrators group (or is the local system account).

If a function requires a particular privilege or privileges, these are usually documented because they need to be enabled.